# How do I set my constructor to have the head and tail point to one sentinel ? (in a singly linked list in c++)

Tags: c++, linked-list

my implementation to set a sentinel to have both head and tail pointing to it is not working.
Here is my code currently.

```
template <typename Type>
SentinelList<Type>::SentinelList(): list_size( 0 ) {
    
    SinglyLinkedNode<Type>* sentinel = new SentinelList<Type>;
    list_head = sentinel;
    list_tail = sentinel;

    list_head->next() = list_tail;
    list_tail->next() = nullptr;

}
```

note:
Node class and list class are already implemented, the next is actually a function call.
EDIT:
i also get this error at last curly brace:

```
[cquery] expected a type
```

EDIT 2:
New error:

```
[cquery] expression is not assignable
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I just want to know if my sentinel implementation is valid. @StephenNewell

Comment: `SinglyLinkedNode<Type>* sentinel = new SentinelList<Type>;` differing types looks weird.

Comment: what type does next() return?

Comment: Discuss with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) where `list_head->next()` and `list_tail->next()` point.

Comment: @MikelF the next() will return the next node, its like that because the node function is in a different header file.

Comment: @notaproatbash that doesn't really answer my question. What type is returned? And further, is this a type you can assign a value to and expect it to be meaningful?

Comment: @MikelF next returns ```SinglyLinkedNode<Type>*``` . the function in its entirety is ```template <typename Type>
SinglyLinkedNode<Type>* SinglyLinkedNode<Type>::next() const {
    return next_node;
}```

Comment: @notaproatbash That `next()` method is returning `next_node` *by value*, so it is not something the caller can modify, hence the error. It needs to return `next_node` *by reference* instead: `SinglyLinkedNode<Type>*& SinglyLinkedNode<Type>::next() const { return next_node; }`

Comment: Please review the code you posted with your rubber duck. (Default-constructing a `SentinelList<Type>` inside its own default constructor is somewhere on the list of Very Bad Ideas.)

Answer (score 2):

Your next() function is returning a value representing a memory address. It is not a reference to a memory location inside the Node instance that can be modified. It is not an l-value that can be assigned to a different value.

Consider changing the code so that the new value is passed to the next() method, such as

```
list_head->next(list_tail);
```

At that point you can actually store the 'new' address value in a memory location that is meaningful.

Beyond that, the following:

```
SinglyLinkedNode<Type>* sentinel = new SentinelList<Type>;
```

is problematic. `sentinel` should be assigned to an object of `SinglyLinkedNode<Type>`